# "More?" in C++ when taking in console input

Tags: c++

I was programming in C++ when I noticed some... odd behavior when taking in console input. Let me explain.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    }

    if (argc >= 2) {
    }
}
```

Pretty simple program, right? Now, when I type in "programName ^" I get a cryptic message, saying "More?" on the console window. On pressing enter, it prompts again and on pressing it once more it closes the application.

Out of curiosity, I tried doing this on some other console input applications I have made and they all do this. What does "More?" mean? I never coded that in, so why is it there?

Comment: I'm guessing you used some sort of continuation character that tells your shell you want to complete your command on another line. What shell/console are you using?

Comment: Command prompt, on windows 10.

Comment: I just tried `dir ^` in a Windows 10 command prompt and got the same thing. It has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Ahh alright, yes, I tried that too. Just googled the '^' symbol and it is the continuation character for cmd. For some reason, this creeped me out a little bit TBH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce the behavior with g++ on Windows.

The DOS shell is interpreting "^" as some kind of "continuation character".

> The ^ symbol (also called caret or circumflex) is an escape character
> in Batch script. When it is used, the next character is interpreted as
> an ordinary character.

Look here for more details:

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/when-did-become-special-on-the-command-line.1071200/

Comment: Impressive spelunking!